# Import s3 csv into PostgreSQL using s3_uri

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

The first SQL statement results in an "ERROR: syntax error at or near \ " 
This refers to s3_uri\gset.

```
psql> SELECT aws_commons.create_s3_uri(
   'test-bucket',
   'animals.csv',
   'us-east-1'
) AS s3_uri \gset

psql> \echo :s3_uri
(test-bucket,animals.csv,us-east-1)

psql> SELECT aws_commons.create_aws_credentials(
   '<my_access_id>',
   '<my_secret_key>',
   '<session_token>'
) AS credentials \gset

psql> \echo :credentials
(<my_access_id>,<my_secret_key>,<session_token>)

psql> SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
   'animals',
   '',
   '(FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER '','', HEADER true)',
   :'s3_uri',
   :'credentials'
);
```

Comment: I believe you have to execute the `SELECT` query without a ';' and then when the continuation line appears do the `\gset`.

Comment: If the first statement yields an error, then how could the second statement show what it shows?